# How to add a color in the <div> bottom content area?

Tags: css

How can I add a color of the bottom part of a `<div>` using CSS? Let's say for example I have a `<div>` with the height of `100px` and I want the `top or upper 50%` of the `<div>` will be shaded with blue and the `50% bottom part` will be shaded with red. So how it is possible?

**NOTE:** Only one `<div>` needs to be use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One div:

```
<div></div>
```

And CSS:

```
div {
    height: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    border-top: solid blue 50px;
    border-bottom: solid red 50px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/A64Lh/

Answer (score 1):

You use CSS Gradient to get this. Gradient will be helpful if you have content in your container.

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height:100px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 0, 255) 50%, rgb(255, 0, 0) 0%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 0, 255) 50%, rgb(255, 0, 0) 0%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 0, 255) 50%, rgb(255, 0, 0) 0%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 0, 255) 50%, rgb(255, 0, 0) 0%);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(0, 0, 255) 50%, rgb(255, 0, 0) 0%);
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/A64Lh/3/)

[CSS Gradient generator link](http://css3gen.com/gradient-generator/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo element. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jusotadi/1/edit)**.

```
div{height:100px; width:100px; background:gold;position:relative;}

div:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height:10px;
  top:0;
  background:blue;
  width: 100px;
}

div:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height:10px;
  bottom:0;
  background:green;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sth like below.

HTML code :

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="red">
    red
    </div>

    <div id="blue">
    blue
    </div>    
 </div>
```

CSS code

```
#box 
{
 outline : solid 3px;  
 color: black;    
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}

#red
{
 background-color:red; 
 height : 50px;   
}

#blue
{
 background-color:blue; 
 height : 50px;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hwGE3/